# How to compare event and HTML tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to compare these codes to boolean value.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="like">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw"></i>
</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#like').on('click', function(event) {

    ...

    var htmlTag = '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw"></i>';
    var isLike = event.target.closest('#like').innerHTML == htmlTag;

    if (isLike) {
        console.log('true');
    } else {
        console.log('false');
    }

    ...

});
```

But it's going to false, In fact it should be true. Why?
Thanks for every answers.

Comment: Why not try `outerHTML` instead?

Comment: The id attribute of an element should be unique for the whole page. This might be contributing to your woes. Also why the check at all? You could change the markup to target the `i` element or use a more specific selector to target it `$('.like i')`

Comment: Thanks for every idea.. It solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.html()` method in order to return the `html` of hyperlink.

```js
$('#like').on('click', function(event) {
    var htmlTag = 'Like<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw"></i>';
    var isLike = $(this).html().trim() == htmlTag;
    if (isLike) {
        console.log('true');
    } else {
        console.log('false');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  id="like">
  Like<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the innerHtml is returning a string with extra spaces use trim() in order to fix it

```
var isLike = event.target.closest('#like').innerHTML.trim() == htmlTag;
```

```js
$('#like').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    var htmlTag = '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw"></i>';
    var isLike = event.target.closest('#like').innerHTML.trim() == htmlTag;


    if (isLike) {
        console.log('true');
    } else {
        console.log('false');
    }

});
```

```css
#like{
height:50px;
width:50px;
border:1px solid;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="like">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: my question it solved. But your answer also great! I'm unexpected to use `.trim()` Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
    var htmlTag = '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw"></i>';
    var isLike = $('#like').html();
    if (htmlTag.trim() === isLike.trim()) {
        console.log('true');
    } else {
        console.log('false');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
Test
</button>

<a href="#" id="like">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: my question it solved. But your answer also great! I'm unexpected to use `.trim()` Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

`event.target.closest('#like').innerHTML` returns you the html in the string format but its with white spaces appended to it. You can use `$.trim()` to remove these white spaces before string comparision.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#like').on('click', function(event) {

    var htmlTag = '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw">Hi</i>';
    alert("#" + event.target.closest('#like').innerHTML + "#");
    var isLike = $.trim(event.target.closest('#like').innerHTML) == htmlTag;

    if (isLike) {
      alert('true');
    } else {
      alert('false');
    }


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="like">
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw">Hi</i>
</a>
```

Comment: Yep! My question it solved. But your answer also great! I'm unexpected to use $.trim(...) Thanks for your answer!